# Spectral radius for block matrix with zero columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, spectral-radius

I have a real matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & A_{12} \\ 
0 & A_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A$ is a square matrix with dimension $N \times N$ and $A_{22}$ is also a square matrix with dimension $N'\times N'$.

I already know the spectral radius for matrix $A$ is $\lambda$. I wonder if we can have an estimated **upper bound** of the spectral radius for submatrix $A_{22}$. It would be great if we can prove that the spectral radius of $A_{22}$ is more or less at the same magnitude with the $\lambda$.

Comment: You use the same notation for matrices and integers, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have a right eigenvector $v$ associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda \ne 0$.  Write it as $v = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 v_2 \end{pmatrix}^T$.  Then
$$ \lambda \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda v = A v = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{12} v_2 \\ A_{22} v_2 \end{pmatrix} $$
Therefore, $v_2$ has to be an eigenvector of $A_{22}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Conversely, for any $v_2$ that is an eigenvector of $A_{22}$ associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda \ne 0$, we can choose $v_1 = A_{12} v_2 / \lambda$ to make the eigenvalue equation above true.  So there is a bijection between eigenvectors of $A$ and eigenvectors of $A_{22}$ with the same eigenvalue.  Therefore, the spectral radius of $A$ has to be the same as the spectral radius of $A_{22}$.

Comment: When I wrote this yesterday, I was somehow imagining that there was a definition of spectral radius that was independent of actual eigenvalues, so I added an unnecessary qualification to the answer.  I'll remove it now.  (Perhaps I was thinking of the spectral norm, which is only equal to the spectral radius for Hermitian matrices, or something along those lines...)